# Using Jquery Mobile in Phonegap Apps for iOS and non-public APIs

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, app-store

I am preparing to send my first iOS app to app store so I was reading AppStore Guideline. 
I created a application with Phonegap using JQuery Mobile Framework.

I have two question:

**1-) I just wonder what this line does mean?**

```
Apps that use non-public APIs will be rejected
```

What are these "non-public APIs"? I have used some API's from github in my app.

**2-) Have I made a mistake using Jquery Mobile?**

```
Apps that are not very useful, unique, are simply web sites bundled as Apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected
```

My app acts like a native app and doesn't need an internet connection. But I don't use objective-c.
And this makes my app a "web sites bundled as App"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Non public APIs are Apple's own undocumented APIs: for example you cannot use UIWebDocumentView because it is an undocumented class that Apple uses in their own apps. If you are not using Objective-C at all this does not concern you.
2. If you are using any open source or commercial framework in your app make sure to check the license to see if you have the rights to use it in your product.
3. What Apple is getting at when talking about useless apps and websites bundled as apps is they don't want apps that serve as advertisement to a brand and have no other specific use but to promote that brand. As long as your app is stable and has a purpose other than self promotion, Apple does not care what technologies you are using to make it.

Comment: Then I must use APIs and libraries that only uses iOS SDK?

Comment: no you can use anything that you have the legal rights to use.